# Temporal information modelling in OWL

Tags: owl, ontology, temporal, owl-api

I found the [time ontology](http://www.w3.org/TR/owl-time/) and saw the way the have approached modelling time and date. I was wondering if there is a way to time stamp the creation of each and every modelling element or axiom in ontologies? Is there an ontology authoring tool that after for example adding "Fred" as an individual will time stamp its creation?

Or, can you think of a way to automate this?

I am working with OWL API directly. So I thought that if I can read date and time variables from the system and have properties such as the ones in time ontology (e.g :hour, :day), then fill in these fields by adding the system's information. Does it sound like a good idea?  Or, is there a more intelligent way towards this.

I am looking for examples to be more efficient and don't bother the user that much with trivial submission of information.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not possible with the default owl api implementation, and there is nothing in the various serialisation formats to store the information.
What can be done within OWL is to add annotations to axioms and entities about their creation, as suggested by Sysoutkoula. The annotations do not need to be text, they can be date time literals.

The other alternative is to extend the owl api implementation to store this information, and persist/recreate the objects with standard serialization to streams, or ad hoc. This is a code intensive task, though, and not interoperable with other tools.

Answer (score 1):

You could add an annotation date with type `dateTimeStamp` every time you add/ edit a class, a property, individual or an axioms.

You could add logger in your code (e.g. [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j)) and log anything you like in a separate file.

Protege editor has various plugins, e.g. [Changes_Tab](http://protegewiki.stanford.edu/wiki/Changes_Tab)

Hope this help.

Comment: Annotation is basically text and that would not help much. I want a better design approach. The same applies to the log; I can log things in another file, but then I need to do some matching. The change tab only records the changes and I can't see any time stamp. I think OWL API is powerful enough to be able to do something. Last resort is what I have suggested above.